# What is the m7601.bin firmware in Debian 11?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, firmware, bugs

While installing Debian 11, in the very early stages the installer warns that it does not have firmware called "m7601.bin". It asks if I have this file on an ejectable media, like a USB stick or floppy. I continued the installation, but realized that the system doesn't recognize my wifi dongle, and that the system sound doesn't work. Could this firmware be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the missing firmware is the cause of the problem.

You need to add `contrib` and `non-free` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` following the second example in [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list).

Then install the `firmware-misc-nonfree` providing the `mt7601u.bin`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
```